# How can I find an international flight number?

Tags: air-travel, missed-flights

I need to know the flight number for the flight to Orlando, Florida, from Gatwick in London, UK in August 2011, via Virgin Airlines, that I missed, but I don't know how to find it. Where can I find the flight number?

Answer (score 1):

As in the linked article, you can look up these details by creating an account on flightstats.com and choosing the historical flight lookup for LGW-MCO. Looking at a random date in August 2011, there were (and still are) two flights daily, the VS27 departing 11:15 and VS15 departing 13:00. If you're looking up the flight for the purposes of determining whether you may be due EU261 compensation, you would obviously need to know what your departure (or arrival) time was in order to look up the delay.

Comment: If you're curious what EC261 compensation is, you can read (or find references) at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation